# Using .htaccess for remove .php extension but folder access returns 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this .htaccess for remove .php in my URLs

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

My files structure is this:

```
css/
es/
-- contact.php
-- index.html
js/
contact.php
index.php
```

What I'm trying to create is a link in my main index.php like this:

```
<a href="es/">Español</a>
```

But when I try to access it, my server returns a 404 error. When I delete the .htaccess, this link works fine, so I guess that I need something else in the .htaccess. Can anybody please guide me on what do I have to add for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With test for php and without folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```